# Python - Why is my version of merge sort destructively sorting the input array?

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm learning Python and some basic data structure and algorithm stuff. I implemented my own version of Merge Sort, and I can't figure out why it's changing the order of the input array. It's behaving as though I referenced the input array as a global in the mergesort() function, which I didn't do. From the way I implemented the code, I think it should be sorting a copy of the input array within the local scope of the function, and then returning a sorted version of that copy, leaving my input array unchanged. However, that's not the case. It sorts the array correctly; I'm just baffled by what seems like a scope problem. I'll include the code and sample output:

```
arr1 = [38,27,43,3,9,82,10,14] #this will be the input array

def mergesort2(array):
    #print("splitting", array)
    if len(array) > 1:
        middle = len(array)//2
        l = array[:middle]
        r = array[middle:]
        
        mergesort2(l)
        mergesort2(r)
        
        i = j = k = 0
        
        while len(l) > 0 and len(r) > 0:
            if l[0] < r[0]:
                array[k] = l.pop(0)
            else:
                array[k] = r.pop(0)
            k = k + 1
        
        while len(l) > 0:
            array[k] = l.pop(0)
            k = k + 1
        
        while len(r) > 0:
            array[k] = r.pop(0)
            k = k + 1
            
    #print("merging",array)
    return array
    
print("input array before mergesort: ", arr1)
s2 = mergesort2(arr1)
print("input array after mergesort: ", arr1)
print("returned array from mergesort: ", s2)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
input array before mergesort:  [38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10, 14]
input array after mergesort:  [3, 9, 10, 14, 27, 38, 43, 82]
returned array from mergesort:  [3, 9, 10, 14, 27, 38, 43, 82]
```

I was expecting to see the input array remain unchanged and to have a new list assigned to "s2" that was a sorted copy of the input array. I appreciate any help in understanding what's happening here!

Comment: Because your function is modifying the array that you pass in. You need to copy it before you pass it to the function. Arguments are **always** passed by object reference in python.

Comment: Every time you do `array[k] = ...` you are mutating the `list` you passed in. Just try that without the merge sort with a simple toy example

Comment: @TheMountainNautilus: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `mersort2` modifies its argument array in place in the merge phase in `array[k] = l.pop(0)` and other similar instructions. If you want it to create a sorted copy, you must allocate a new array and merge into that, including if the argument array has less than 2 elements:

```
def mergesort2(array):
    res = array[:]
    if len(array) > 1:
        middle = len(array) // 2
        l = mergesort2(array[:middle])
        r = mergesort2(array[middle:])
        i = j = k = 0
        while i < len(l) and j < len(r):
            if l[i] < r[j]:
                res[k] = l[i]
                i = i + 1
            else:
                res[k] = r[j]
                j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
        
        while i < len(l):
            res[k] = l[i]
            i = i + 1
            k = k + 1
        
        # no need to copy remaining elements from r
    return res
    
arr1 = [38,27,43,3,9,82,10,14] #this will be the input array
print("input array before mergesort: ", arr1)
s2 = mergesort2(arr1)
print("input array after mergesort: ", arr1)
print("returned array from mergesort: ", s2)
```

Output:

```
input array before mergesort:  [38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10, 14]
input array after mergesort:  [38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10, 14]
returned array from mergesort:  [3, 9, 10, 14, 27, 38, 3, 14]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not a scoping problem, it's how Python works. Python passes objects like lists by reference. That is, when you pass it as an argument to your function, the list isn't copied. I would recommend copying the input array before passing it as an argument.

Comment: _"passes mutable objects"_ should just be _"passes objects"._ Even immutable objects are passed by object reference

Comment: No, nothing is *ever passed by reference* and the *type of the argument is irrelevant*. All objects are "call by object sharing"

Comment: My mistake! I've fixed it. In my defense, passing immutable objects is exempt from the type of errors shown in the problem.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the feedback. That's different behavior than I expected. I just played with some toy examples to try to clarify that behavior for myself, and I think I get how that works. Your answers also helped me find some more to read about how variables work in Python, so thank you very much! I think I was assuming that variables are always passed by value, not reference.

Comment: Is Python weird for the way it treats variables? Now I'm reading about shallow vs. deep copying, and can't help but wonder why everything is an object with pointers in Python, rather than a location in memory with a variable name that you can use to change that memory location. I've also decided to pick programming up again after about 15 years away from it, and the last language I knew somewhat well was Pascal, so it's not like I have a great point of reference for what's weird or not.